# Pushing single file change in the azure app service deployment

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I have an asp.net core web application and I deploy the application from my Visual Studio 2015 by publishing. But every time I change something I need to publish the whole application again.

Is there any way to deploy the application partially? For example, if there is a very small change in a file, I can only send that file in the app service directly without publishing the entire application again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. You have a few options.

1. If it's a change to a text file, you can edit the file directly on the server by navigating to https://[yourAppName].scm.azurewebsites.net. Log in with your credentials that you use to access the portal.azure.com site. Navigate to Debug Console -> CMD. This will give you a sort of online file explorer. You can choose any file to edit right there in the browser. This is handy for those small edits. But beware making edits on the server and forgetting to commit them to your source control management solution.
2. For binary files, you can upload them directly via FTP. You can find your FTP creds by downloading your web app's publish profile on the Overview blade for your web app. FTP into the server and replace any file that you like.

Comment: Are changes made via FTP maintained if/when the app service instance is replicated?